# prediction error in GLM

Tags: generalized-linear-model, predictive-models, error

Can you please explain why this statement holds?

a distribution where the variance is proportional to the mean will better tolerate larger prediction errors occurring with larger predictions than one whose variance is independent of the mean.

Comment: Because the variance is proportional to the mean function, as the modelled mean increases, so does the modelled variance associated with those responses. The underlying model is suggesting that variance *should* increase with the mean.

Comment: Thanks. But, can you please tell me about the relationship between the variance and prediction error?

Comment: If you have a bigger variance, I am assuming the prediction error will be bigger as a result. Can you please verify this?

Answer (score 2):

Consider the case of a Poisson GLM. In this case, the variance is directly equal to the mean
$$\mathbb{E}[Y\,|\,X]=\text{Var}(Y\,|\,X)=\mu_{i}$$

For example:

[image]

Obviously for higher $\mu_{i}$, the model admits larger deviations away from $\mu_{i}$ with higher probabilities. Depending on how you define *prediction error*, those larger deviations result in lower *error* for larger $\mu_{i}$.

Essentially, the model is happier with seeing large deviations from the prediction for increasing $\mu_{i}$. This is a property of the chosen model. In practice, this might not be something you want for your model. You may want the model to have a variance that is homogenous across the support of the distribution (homoscedasticity).